# To control the elements present in object tag in html page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How to apply jquery click function to the element present in the `object` tag

Lets consider welcome.html consists of

```
var ttw = "www.geh.com:2909/";    
$("#nod2").html('<object style="height:288px;" id="55cr" data="'+ ttw + '"/>');
```

It results in the welcome.html as

```
<html>
  <body>
    <script>
      //How to alert('WELCOME'); on click on P tag in object
    </script>
    <object data="www.geh.com:2909/" id="55cr">
      <html>
        <body>
          <p id="tpr">Helloo dude!</p>
        </body> 
      </html>
    </object>
  </body> 
</html>
```

Now how can I `alert();`  on click on `p` tag in `object`.
I tried using

```
$("#tpr").click( function(e) {
    alert('WELCOME');
});
```

It doesn't worked.
How can I achieve it.

Comment: empty alert function will still alert, but it will just alert `undefined`

Comment: It seams that the `p`tag is not accessible within the `object` tag.  It is not even showing http://jsfiddle.net/daguru/gw9Pc/

Answer (score 1):

You need to use  [**Event Delegation**](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/). You have to use [**.on()**](http://api.jquery.com/on/) using delegated-events approach.

i.e.

```
$(document).on('event','selector',callback_function)
```

Example

```
$(document).on('click', '#tpr', function () {
         alert('ha');
});
```

Ideally you should replace `document` with closest static container. **document** will work

Comment: Its not working. "closest static container" means object tag id?

Answer (score 0):

You need to delegate the click event since the object element is rendered after the DOM has loaded.

```
$(document.body).on('click', '#tpr', function (e) {
     alert();
});
```

Comment: If you are using the latest jquery use `.on()` rather that the deprecated `.delegate()`.....my bad